# Connected to wifi but no Internet using a usb adapter

Tags: wireless, internet, alfa-wireless

I'm using an ALFA Network adapter to connect to a Wi-Fi. It works fine in Windows(using it right now), but when I go to Ubuntu, the Internet doesn't work. The driver is installed correctly as far as I can tell, it says the connection to the Wi-Fi is established but when I try to load a page it says connection lost or page can't be loaded, I also tried downloading something from a terminal, shows the same problem(connection lost).

What could be causing this? How to fix it?

This is the result of pinging on the google DNS.

> ping 8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. From
>   192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=3
>   Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=4 Destination
>   Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host
>   Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable From
>   192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=10
>   Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=11 Destination
>   Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host
>   Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable From
>   192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=16 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=17
>   Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=18 Destination
>   Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=19 Destination Host
>   Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=20 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=21 Destination Host Unreachable From
>   192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=22 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=23 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=24
>   Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=25 Destination
>   Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=26 Destination Host
>   Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=27 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=28 Destination Host Unreachable From
>   192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=29 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=30 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=31
>   Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=32 Destination
>   Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=33 Destination Host
>   Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=34 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=35 Destination Host Unreachable From
>   192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=36 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=37 Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=38
>   Destination Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=39 Destination
>   Host Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=40 Destination Host
>   Unreachable From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=41 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.9 icmp_seq=42 Destination Host Unreachable ^C
>   --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 43 packets transmitted, 0 received, +42 errors, 100% packet loss, time 42146ms pipe 4

Comment: Have you tried pinging sites and their IP addresses?  For example, ping www.google.com, and then 8.8.8.8.  Let us know the output.

Comment: @ServiceManager updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have a "default route" set up.

```
ip route
```

will show you your routes.

```
iwconfig
```

will let you find your Wifi device name (device names are in the first column - pick the one that does NOT say `no wireless extensions.`

For the following example, to set up a "default" route on `wlan0`, where `<IP>` is the IP address of your router,

```
sudo route add default via <IP> dev wlan0
```